# Hearthstone Style Deck Stats for TCG

Tags: java, game

Right now I have this messy method to collect the deck statistics while building a window that will display those statistics.  These statistics are things like the type and mana cost of the card.  I know that this method is too large, so I would like to get some advice for how to make it smaller.

The challenge is that I have to check if the current property in the for loop matches certain predetermined strings before putting the updated information back into the map.  This is messy now, but it will get much messier later when even more properties need to be evaluated.

Here is the method:

```
private void buildDeckInfoBox() {
    this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().clear();

    Map<Integer, Integer> manaCostValues = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> scrapCostValues = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> creatureTypes = new HashMap<>();

    for (int cardId : this.activeDeckConfig.getChosen().keySet()) {

        CardInfoMessage card = this.cardList.get(cardId);
        int cardCount = this.activeDeckConfig.getChosen().get(cardId);

        for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : card.getProperties().entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = String.valueOf(entry.getValue());

            //The value is used as the key for the new map
            //increment the number of cards and put it back in the map
            if (key.equals("creatureType")) {
                if (creatureTypes.get(value) == null) {
                    creatureTypes.put(value, cardCount);
                } else {
                    int creatureCount = creatureTypes.get(value);
                    int newCreatureCount = creatureCount + cardCount;
                    creatureTypes.put(value, newCreatureCount);
                }
            } else if (key.equals("MANA_COST")) {
                if (manaCostValues.get(Integer.parseInt(value)) == null) {
                    manaCostValues.put(Integer.parseInt(value), cardCount);
                } else {
                    int manaCostCount = manaCostValues.get(Integer.parseInt(value));
                    int newManaCostCount = manaCostCount + cardCount;
                    manaCostValues.put(Integer.parseInt(value), newManaCostCount);
                }
            } else if (key.equals("SCRAP_COST")) {
                if (scrapCostValues.get(Integer.parseInt(value)) == null) {
                    scrapCostValues.put(Integer.parseInt(value), cardCount);
                } else {
                    int scrapCostCount = scrapCostValues.get(Integer.parseInt(value));
                    int newScrapCostCount = scrapCostCount + cardCount;
                    scrapCostValues.put(Integer.parseInt(value), newScrapCostCount);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int manaCost : manaCostValues.keySet()) {
        Label manaCostLabel = new Label();
        manaCostLabel.setText(String.format("Mana Cost = %d, Count = %d", manaCost, manaCostValues.get(manaCost)));
        this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().add(manaCostLabel);
    }
    for (int scrapCost : scrapCostValues.keySet()) {
        Label scrapCostLabel = new Label();
        scrapCostLabel.setText(String.format("Scrap Cost = %d, Count = %d", scrapCost, scrapCostValues.get(scrapCost)));
        this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().add(scrapCostLabel);
    }
    for (String creatureType : creatureTypes.keySet()) {
        Label creatureTypeLabel = new Label();
        creatureTypeLabel.setText(String.format("Creature Type %s, Count = %d", creatureType, creatureTypes.get(creatureType)));
        this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().add(creatureTypeLabel);
    }
}
```

Here is an example of the output:

[image]

Eventually I will turn these labels into a fancy statistics graph like the one in Hearthstone, separated by the type of property.

Comment: At a quick glance this code looks overall good, but it looks like it could be separated or organised into methods a little bit, not too too much until your program gets bigger, but to keep it maintainable I would suggest separating it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, there are only three specific keys that you are interested in, so there is no need to loop over the map. Just grab the keys that are interesting and see if they are null or not.

Secondly, it's possible to extract a method for increasing the actual card counts in each map.

```
Object creatureType = card.getProperties().get("creatureType");
Object manaCost = card.getProperties().get("MANA_COST");
Object scrapCost = card.getProperties().get("SCRAP_COST");
if (creatureType != null) {
    increase(creatureTypes, (String) creatureType, cardCount);
}
if (manaCost != null) {
    increase(manaCostValues, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(manaCost)), cardCount);
}
if (scrapCost != null) {
    increase(scrapCostValues, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(scrapCost)), cardCount);
}
```

Where the `increase` method is:

```
private <T> void increase(Map<T, Integer> map, T key, int cardCount) {
    if (map.get(key) == null) {
        map.put(key, cardCount);
    } else {
        int oldValue = map.get(key);
        int newValue = oldValue + cardCount;
        map.put(key, newValue);
    }
}
```

Now, the folks over at Oracle noticed that this was a very common pattern in code, so in Java 8 they introduced the `Map.merge` method:

```
private <T> void increase(Map<T, Integer> map, T key, int cardCount) {
    map.merge(key, cardCount, (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

---

**But what about this pattern?**

```
Object creatureType = card.getProperties().get("creatureType");
if (creatureType != null) {
    increase(creatureTypes, (String) creatureType, cardCount);
}
```

Well, the new Java 8 `Optional` class to the rescue!

```
Optional.ofNullable(card.getProperties().get("creatureType"))
    .ifPresent(obj -> increase(creatureTypes, (String) obj, cardCount));
```

---

**So your entire code can be changed to:**

```
private void buildDeckInfoBox() {
    this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().clear();

    Map<Integer, Integer> manaCostValues = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> scrapCostValues = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, Integer> creatureTypes = new HashMap<>();

    for (int cardId : this.activeDeckConfig.getChosen().keySet()) {

        CardInfoMessage card = this.cardList.get(cardId);
        int cardCount = this.activeDeckConfig.getChosen().get(cardId);

        Optional.ofNullable(card.getProperties().get("creatureType"))
            .ifPresent(obj -> increase(creatureTypes, (String) obj, cardCount));
        Optional.ofNullable(card.getProperties().get("MANA_COST"))
            .ifPresent(obj -> increase(manaCostValues, (Integer) obj, cardCount));
        Optional.ofNullable(card.getProperties().get("SCRAP_COST"))
            .ifPresent(obj -> increase(scrapCostValues, (Integer) obj, cardCount));
    }

    for (int manaCost : manaCostValues.keySet()) {
        Label manaCostLabel = new Label();
        manaCostLabel.setText(String.format("Mana Cost = %d, Count = %d", manaCost, manaCostValues.get(manaCost)));
        this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().add(manaCostLabel);
    }
    for (int scrapCost : scrapCostValues.keySet()) {
        Label scrapCostLabel = new Label();
        scrapCostLabel.setText(String.format("Scrap Cost = %d, Count = %d", scrapCost, scrapCostValues.get(scrapCost)));
        this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().add(scrapCostLabel);
    }
    for (String creatureType : creatureTypes.keySet()) {
        Label creatureTypeLabel = new Label();
        creatureTypeLabel.setText(String.format("Creature Type %s, Count = %d", creatureType, creatureTypes.get(creatureType)));
        this.deckInfoLabelBox.getChildren().add(creatureTypeLabel);
    }
}

private <T> void increase(Map<T, Integer> map, T key, int cardCount) {
    map.merge(key, cardCount, (a, b) -> a + b);
}
```

---

It *is* possible to refactor those last three for loops as well, but I am not sure if it is entirely worth it. Perhaps I'll show how to do that some other time.